# How to compare two array and mismatch based on index using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a=["a","b","c","d"];
var b=["b","a","c","d"];
```

I need output like:

mismatched array from a

mismatch array=`["a", "b"];`

Comment: Welcome to SO. We encourage you to add any code you've attempted to solve this to your question as a [mcve]. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: `const mismatch = a.reduce((acc,curr,i) => (curr != b[i] ? acc.push(curr) : 0, acc), [])`

Comment: But also checkout [the documentation on loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried. A simple `for` loop with a comparison between `a[i]` with `b[i]` and adding it to ouptut array should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function and check value with the index in both the array and then you can get the mismatched values from a.

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var b = ["b", "a", "c", "d"];

var c = a.filter(function (item, index) {
  return item !== b[index];
});

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I used Javascript's filter method to get the mismatched Array.

```
const a = ["a","b","c","d"];
const b = ["b","a","c","d"];

const mismatchedArr = a.filter((aItem,index) => aItem !== b[index]);
console.log(mismatchedArr); //Prints ["a","b"]
```